# loop through a JSONObject

Tags: java, android, arrays, json

I am having trouble understanding how can I loop through a JSONArray like this one-----
      [
        {"A": "a", "X": "x"},
        {"A": "a1", "X": "x1"},
        {"A": "a2", "X": "x2"}
        {"A": "a3", "X": "x3"}
      ]
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: try writing some code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
JSONArray a = ...;
for (int i = 0; i < a.length(); i++) {
    JSONObject o = a.getJSONObject(i);
    // do something with o
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I was confused between accessing JSONObject/JSONArray. You cleared the doubt.

Comment: Yeah, the JSONObject API is kind of dense and not the greatest to work with.